# Walk cycle movement using Rigid Bodies

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I was just thinking if it was possible to make a person walk if I make the walk cycle and then just make it interact with the terrain using rigid bodies or something of that sort. The basic idea is to not animate the movement of the object, let physics do the work.

If the above mentioned is not possible please suggest a way to animate a walk more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can. But you can better make the animated rig a dynamic body with capsule bounds in collision bounds. try to ajust the hight so the feet will touch the ground. to do this, just move the origin of the rig. Now just use programming with velocity motion to make it walk and try to change the animation according to the speed you want it to walk. Cause with physics like that, I think it wil lag a lot because it will try to sufficate with the underground. And in that case you should use triangle mesh bounds witch ask a lot more from your pc / mac / linux thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the later part makes a lot more sense. My computer is not that powerful so I guess it will lag. Will have to stick to the traditional ways. Though can you suggest ways to do that faster?

Comment: I can't, it's the way I always do it. But I'm sure there are other people who are.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I imagine this is the kind of "interact with the terrain" you wanted? If yes, then it's just as simple as making any rigid body physics. You simply parent a rigid body hit box to your leg bones, and then you animate whatever motions you want and bake it in rigid body world section under scene property tab.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is not the entire thing that I wanted. This does me a rough idea of how I might be able to do it. I had planned to make a walk cycle and let the rigid bodies do the job of moving the character forward. I am not entirely sure if that is possible according to your current explanation. So it will be helpful if you can elaborate it please.

Comment: Oh you mean a ragdoll system like they do in GTA iv?